# R, Substitute NAs by zero

Tags: r, zoo

How can I substitute `NA` values by zero in a R zoo series?
I've been reading about `na.locf` and `na.omit`  but I think none of them do what I need.

thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Zoo Series but this is how you do it with vectors. This Should work.

```
x = c(NA,1,2,3)
x[ is.na(x) ] <- 0 
print (x)
```

Comment: This method will not work if we have multiple time series as a zoo object

Answer (score 3):

Use `na.fill`.  If `z` is the zoo series:

```
na.fill(z, fill = 0)
```